# XPath get node like

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm quite challenged with the following problem.

My XML contains several orders with a status. They are grouped together by appending integers to the tags. It would be easier if each order had it's own parent tag but this is the way I get the XML from an external application and I cannot change it.

```
<Values>
    <ORDER_1>506137</ORDER_1>
    <STATUS_1>3</STATUS_1>

    <ORDER_2>506129</ORDER_2>
    <STATUS_2>4</STATUS_2>

    <ORDER_3>51893</ORDER_3>
    <STATUS_3>1</STATUS_3>
</Values>
```

What I need to do is find the order that corresponds to status '4'. Is it even possible with XPath? It seems like I need a wildcard to select the status, but even then how do I find the corresponding order?

FYI: XPath 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to filter node name using XPath `name()` and `starts-with()` function, then use `preceding-sibling` to select corresponding order element, for example :

```
//Values/*[starts-with(name(), 'STATUS_')][.=4]/preceding-sibling::*[1]
```

Above XPath will return this node :

```
<ORDER_2>506129</ORDER_2>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you see any way to eliminate the dependancy of all nodes being in the same order? So by not using preceding-sibling. It seems error prone if the external application is to add a new tag.

Comment: You can filter preceding sibling by name to avoid the query confuses order tag with other tag if any, for example : `....preceding-sibling::*[starts-with(name(), 'ORDER_')][1]`

Comment: and if you're not sure whether the `ORDER_N` will be before or after the `STATUS_N` then use `../*[starts-with(....)]` (all siblings, preceding or following) instead of `preceding-sibling::*[....]`